# How to generate Sequence starting with Max Id of a table

Tags: sql-server, sequence

I am trying to create a sequence using this DML and I get this error:

> Incorrect syntax near '@maxBookingId'.

Code:

```
 DECLARE @maxBookingId AS INT 

 SELECT @maxBookingId = MAX(bookingid) 
 FROM booking

 CREATE SEQUENCE Invoice_Seq  AS INTEGER  
 START WITH @maxBookingId
 INCREMENT BY 1  
 NO CYCLE;
```

How can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unfortunately, no variables here. Use dynamic SQL instead:

```
declare @maxBookingId as int 
select @maxBookingId = max(bookingid) from booking
declare @s nvarchar(4000);
set @s = N'
CREATE SEQUENCE Invoice_Seq  AS INTEGER  
START WITH ' + cast(@maxBookingId as nvarchar) + '
INCREMENT BY 1  
NO CYCLE;'

EXEC (@s);
```

Answer (score 2):

The [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff878091.aspx) states it must be a constant. To get around it, you should be able to use dynamic SQL.